# Why Adding window.location.href in _app.js Next making always reload page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I want to make authentication. if the user is not logged in it will be redirected to the login page. I added that condition in the Provider file and implemented it in _app.js. after I added this file:

```
 const reds = () => {
            if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
                if(!user){
                    window.location.href = '/login'
                }else if(pathname === '/login' && user){
                    window.location.href = '/'
                }else{
                    window.location.href = '/'
                }
            }
        }
```

The website page will always reload .. **how should I solve this? how to make auth redirect in next js correct?**
*the full code is below*

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import configureStore from '../store'

const { store, persistor } = configureStore()

const AuthProvider = props => {
    console.log("fasdfasd")
    const [user, setUser] = useState(true)

    const { pathname, events } = useRouter()
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleRouteChange = url => {
        if(!user){
            window.location.href = '/login'
        }else if(pathname === '/login' && user){
            window.location.href = '/'
        }else{
            window.location.href = '/'
        }
    }

    const reds = () => {
        if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
            if(!user){
                window.location.href = '/login'
            }else if(pathname === '/login' && user){
                window.location.href = '/'
            }else{
                window.location.href = '/'
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        reds()
    },[pathname])

    useEffect(() => {
        events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
        return () => {
            events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
        }
    },[user])

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                { props.children }
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthProvider
```

Comment: maybe need to remove last else : else{
                    window.location.href = '/'
                }

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend you use Next.js `router.push()` rather than `window.location`.

Answer (score 0):

reload is `windows.loaction.href` default behaviour. use `router.push("/login")`

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAGuC.png)

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
const pathName = usePathname()

windows.loaction.pathname => pathName

Comment: Please mention what the link actually provides and change the generic description on that image